# order by in lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects, lambda

I'm trying to sort the data in lambda expression in the following case.

```
if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorLogPath"].ToString())))
{
    string path = Server.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorLogPath"].ToString());
    // a.Select(p => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p));
    var a = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    if (a != null)
    {
        Session["gvData"] = a.ToList();
        BindDataToGrid();
    }
}
```

In `var` `a` i get list of complete path of files like

```
c:\\logfiles\\01022012.txt.
```

How can I get `var` `a` sorted on basis of `01022012`
I tried

```
var a = Directory.GetFiles(path).OrderBy(p=>Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p));
```

but not working. Is there any thing am I doing wrong?

Getting result as

```
"C:\\LogFiles\\01112012.txt" 
"C:\\LogFiles\\08102012.txt" 
"C:\\LogFiles\\14092012.txt" 
"C:\\LogFiles\\15102012.txt" 
"C:\\LogFiles\\17102012.txt" 
"C:\\LogFiles\\19092012.txt"
```

Expected is

```
"C:\\LogFiles\\14092012.txt" 
"C:\\LogFiles\\19092012.txt" 
"C:\\LogFiles\\08102012.txt" 
"C:\\LogFiles\\15102012.txt" 
"C:\\LogFiles\\17102012.txt" 
"C:\\LogFiles\\01112012.txt"
```

Comment: It's not clear where LINQ to Entities fits in here - you're using `Directory.GetFiles()`, so that's an in-memory data source, so you're using LINQ to Objects. Next, please clarify what you mean by "not working" - what *exactly* are you seeing?

Comment: not working means i get same result as not applying .OrderBy(p=>Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p));
i get data but not sorted one.

Comment: I suspect your diagnostics are incorrect, or the filenames were already sorted. Please provide a short but *complete* example, the expected result and the actual result.

Comment: Getting result as 
"C:\\LogFiles\\01112012.txt"
"C:\\LogFiles\\08102012.txt"
"C:\\LogFiles\\14092012.txt"
"C:\\LogFiles\\15102012.txt"
"C:\\LogFiles\\17102012.txt"
"C:\\LogFiles\\19092012.txt"
Expected is
"C:\\LogFiles\\14092012.txt"
"C:\\LogFiles\\19092012.txt"
"C:\\LogFiles\\08102012.txt"
"C:\\LogFiles\\15102012.txt"
"C:\\LogFiles\\17102012.txt"
"C:\\LogFiles\\01112012.txt"

Comment: sorry lazyberezovsky for not marking answer as marked. yes some of the answers helped me. i marked them.

Comment: You still haven't provided a short but complete example of how you're seeing the results. Please edit the *question* to include those details. (A console application would be simplest.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = Directory.GetFiles(path)
                 .OrderBy(p => Regex.Replace(p,@"^.*\\(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d).*$","$3$2$1"))
```

The order worked but was an alphabetical order, whereas you want a chronological order.
The trick is to turn ddMMyyyy into yyyyMMdd (thanks to the regex) and then then alphabetical and chronological orders become identical.

Comment: thanks Ssithra. it worked. i am understanding regular expression. its sorting in ascending order. what changes i need to do to make it sorting descending ?

Comment: @SarangAmrutkar use `.OrderByDescending`